# Adding custom html attribute to Ember.select

Tags: ember.js

My dropdown menu is generating using following code

```
{{view Ember.Select contentBinding="controller.softwares" valueBinding="ss.value" optionLabelPath="content.name" optionValuePath="content.id" prompt="Select Software" name="software" }}
```

Currently it is generating something like

```
<select name="software">
......
</select>
```

I want it to be

```
<select name="software" data-id="45">
......
</select>
```

I tried

```
{{view Ember.Select contentBinding="controller.softwares" valueBinding="ss.value" optionLabelPath="content.name" optionValuePath="content.id" prompt="Select Software" name="software" data-id="ss.id" }}
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell Ember to bind this attribute:

```
App.YourSelect = Ember.Select.extend({
  attributeBindings : ["data-id"]
});

{{view App.YourSelect contentBinding=controller.softwares valueBinding=ss.value optionLabelPath="content.name" optionValuePath="content.id" prompt="Select Software" name="software" data-id=ss.id }}
```

This tells ember to add this attribute to the underlying DOM element. **Plz also note my slight corrections of removals of ".** It's a advice by the Ember Team to use no quotes, when you are accessing an object. This should make it easier to distinguish it from Strings like "Select Software".

**PS:** Haven't tested it. There may be little bugs :-)

Comment: `It's a advice by the Ember Team to use no quotes, when you are accessing an object.` Why is it so ??? Any explanations ???

Comment: Imagine `{{view propertyA="foo" propertyB=bar}}`. With this advice it is clear that propertyA is assigned a String, whereas property B is assigned an object from the current context.

Comment: http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/08/29/ember-1-0-rc8.html - Have a look at the part "ENFORCE QUOTED STRINGS IN HANDLEBARS HELPERS". They explain their reasons there.

Comment: Yeah unquoting comes mainly for supporting paths in `link-to`. But still binding objects with quotes works right http://jsfiddle.net/Selvaganesh/T25f2/2/

Comment: Anywyz i will go with the convention `quotes for strings, no quotes for paths.` :)

Comment: It seems it is adding data-id attribute but value is not binding with it. It is generating <select id="ember880" class="ember-view ember-select" name="software" data-id="ss.id">

Comment: Yeah it worked after it've added data-idBinding=ss.id instead of data-id=ss.id

Comment: Ah yes you are right, i will correct the answer later this day.